# PhoneGap App working on simulator, but not properly on iPhone device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cordova

I'm developing an iOS app. Its working properly on simulator.

I'm using phonegap and child browser. On device only for the first time child browser is working. After I closed the childbrowser(pressed done button) its not opening again when I tried to open it.

But working perfectly on simulator. Any help.
Did anyone faced similar problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its working perfectly now. Just changed the childbrowser.js file to a new one which i found [here](http://github.com/thechaithanya/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/iPhone/)

There are slight changes in the childbrowser plugin, as per the changes in the phonegap's new new version I think.

Comment: How you have used this?Please tell me,as I am having similar kind of problem in my phonegap application,tell me how you have fixed it?

Comment: It's been a while and I'm not working on it anymore. But, AFAIR : using ChildBrowser hat is compatible with the PhoneGap I was using then solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

are you calling it in the same way?
Do you have any onClose callbacks?

Hard to tell without seeing some code.

Comment: it's the same code which is working on the simulator. Working only for the first time I installed on device.